# reverse index table in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing, reverse

I am new to mongodb.I have this type of collection structure.

```
{
     "user1":["l1","l2","l3","l4","l5"]
     "user2":["l2","l3",l4","l7"]
     "user3":["l7,"l5"]
}
```

So I want to convert this collection into reverse index form

```
{
      "l1":[user1]
      "l2":[user1,user2]
      "l3":[user1,user2]
      "l4":[user1,user2]
      "l5":[user1,user3]
      "l7":[user2,user3]
}
```

How can I write the mongodb query for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should understand that in your document user* and l* is very different entities. Since Mongo stored JSON documents, user is a key and l* is a value. I believe there is no way to convert one to another using only Mongo query. If you need to use exactly this document scheme, you should use some application to download data from Mongo and proceed it. You can use Java Script in Mongo Console as the simplest way.
Another was is to change scheme to

```
   {'name':'user1', 'l':['l1','l2','l3','l4','l5']}
   {'name':'user2', 'l':['l2','l3','l4','l7']}
   {'name':'user3', 'l':['l7','l5']}
```

and then use aggregation framework

```
db.users.aggregate([{$unwind:'$l'},{$group:{_id:'$l',users:{$push:'$name'}}}])
```